# Create and convert .rpt to .pdf without ReportViewer

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, email-attachments

I'm writing a function on a button click that allow the user to send an email to a list of customers which an attached .pdf of the invoice, which is made using Crystal Reports. I've got the email function working, I can retrieve the correct information and send an email to each customer in the list, but I'm having trouble with the attachment side of things.

In the same project, I do have a window with a ReportViewer on that I'm using to generate and view individual reports, however, due to the large amount of reports that potentially are being created and sent at once, I need to now create them without using this window.

Is it possible to generate a report and then convert it to .pdf without using a ReportViewer, and if so, how can I do this?

I thought maybe by using SQL to select all of the data that I need and store it in a DataSet, but I'm not sure what would need doing after this.

Comment: you mean you dont need to show the report physically?

Comment: @reds Yes, I don't need to show it, just create it and then set it as an email attachment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually more simple than I think you're imagining it to be.

Just setup the login info for the database required, then retrieve the data from the database using SQL, and store it in a `DataSet`, which you set to be the reports `DataSource`, then export it. Obviously you may have different ways of doing things but this should roughly do it

```
Dim report As New ReportDocument

                Dim dest As String = ` This is where you put your file destination
                report.Load(dest)

                Dim info As CrystalDecisions.Shared.TableLogOnInfo
                info = New CrystalDecisions.Shared.TableLogOnInfo()

                info.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = ' Your DB name
                info.ConnectionInfo.ServerName =' Your DB server name
                info.ConnectionInfo.Password = ' Your DB password
                info.ConnectionInfo.UserID = ' Your DB UserID
                report.Database.Tables(0).ApplyLogOnInfo(info)

                sql = "SELECT * FROM your_table"
                Dim rda As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, connectionstring)
                Dim rds As New DataSet
                rda.Fill(rds)

                report.SetDataSource(rds)

                CrDiskFileDestinationOptions.DiskFileName = ' Your directory path and chosen file name
                CrExportOptions = report.ExportOptions

                With CrExportOptions
                    .ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile
                    .ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat
                    .DestinationOptions = CrDiskFileDestinationOptions
                    .FormatOptions = CrFormatTypeOptions
                End With

                report.Export()
```